# Meaning of を in 東京都庁をスタートする

Tags: grammar, particle-を

> 「東京マラソン」は、東京都庁**を**スタートして、銀座や浅草など観光地を走る人気のマラソン大会です。
>   The Tokyo Marathon is a popular race that runs through tourist areas like Ginza and Asakusa and starts **at** the government office.

Clearly this を is not the object particle (the race isn't starting the office). I know that を can also mean 'through' like the second time it appears above. But I'm sure the race doesn't start **through** the office either.

So を must have another meaning I don't know, or it's a typo for で. I assume the former.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24090/9831　・　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15221/9831　・　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21313/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a slightly exceptional (and very important) usage of 「**を**」 employed with ***motion verbs*** that actually are **intransitive** verbs.

「東京都庁{とうきょうとちょう}**を**スタートして」 = "(the marathon) starts ***at*** the Tokyo Metropolitan Government Building and"

「銀座{ぎんざ}や浅草{あさくさ}など観光地{かんこうち}**を**走{はし}る」 = "(it) runs ***through*** the sight-seeing spots such as Ginza and Asakusa"

Both 「スタートする」 and 「走る」 are intransitive verbs here.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I don't really think of 'start' as a motion verb. I'll just chalk this one up to a **very** exceptional usage.

Comment: I am talking about 「スタートする」; I am not talking about "to start" at all.  Once it begins, a marathon is all about moving.  If you don't really understand 「～～をスタートする」, I would have to wonder how  you would「～～を走る」.  Both are intransitive verbs, but they can take 「を」 ONLY because both express "motion", "movement", etc.  To talk about traveling, for instance, we often use 「～～をスタートする」,「～～を出発する」, etc.  Again, both are intransitive.

Comment: In which case, I clearly don't understand スタートする at all. I assumed it was a synonym for 'to begin' which doesn't really involve movement. Could you please enlighten me on how you understand スタートする? Thanks. For 走る I see the を as 'along' or 'through' and that normally works for me.