# を/に・通る particle help

Tags: particles, transitivity

In the sentence,

> 毎日、この道を通ります。

why is を used? Wouldn't it be に?
Also,

> 試験に通る

I thought the verb was intransitive, so I thought it would be が maybe. "the test was passed" ?

Any helpful explanations?

Comment: Related (regarding 「道を通る」, 「～を+intransitive verb」): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6869/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24090/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21313/9831

Answer (score 1):

It's challenging to provide an exhaustive answer for your question. I recommend you leverage the [existing posts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%81%AB+%E3%82%92+verb) in this forum explaining the basics, and supplement with these examples tailored for you:

> In the sentence, 毎日、この道を通ります。 why is を used?

**Example to use を - 1**

- Question E: what are you walking **on** (top of)?
- Question J: 何(の上)**を** walking していますか？

↓

- Answer E: I am walking **on** (top of) the 道.
- Answer J: 道(の上)**を** walking しています。

---

**Example to use を - 2**

- Question E: what are you searching **for**?
- Question J: 何**を** searching していますか？

↓

- Answer E: I am searching **for** the 道.
- Answer J: 道**を** searching しています。

---

**Example to use に - 1**

- Question E: what are you angry **at**?
- Question J: 何**に** angry ですか？

↓

- Answer E: I am angry **at** the 道.
- Answer J: 道**に** angry です。

---

**Example to use に - 2**

- Question E: where are you throwing **against**?
- Question J: どこ**に** throwing してますか？

↓

- Answer E: I am throwing **against** the 道.
- Answer J: 道**に** throwing しています。

---

Consider using **に** when pointing to a target. Shout **against**, scream **towards**, ask a question **to**, etc. There are exceptions, but it's a good starting point.

---

> Also, 試験に通る I thought the verb was intransitive, so I thought it would be が maybe.

This is a brilliant obvservation. If we were to use **が** , it would mean:

- J: 試験**が**通る
- E: 試験 **is** passing by (as in, "Mr. 試験 is passing by your desk")

So it's simply wrong unless you're talking about an entity called 試験 who is actually passing by.

---

Let's remember the tip: "Consider using **に** when pointing to a target".

The target here is 試験. When we say "passed the exam", what did we **do** (verb) against the exam?

- We did **not**: "**pass** against the exam".
- We: "**accomplished** a result of passing, against the exam".

Therefore, the verb is **not** 通る. Accomplish (e.g. 結果を出す) is the hidden verb.

- 試験に 通過するという 結果を出す。
- Against (the target which is) exam, pass is the result I delivered.

↓ people like to cut down components, resulting with...

- 試験に 通<s>過す</s>る <s>(という結果を出す)</s>。
- I passed the exam.